# Laravel : An "updated_at" and "created_at" field found when adding data on my table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

When i update my table with data there is a two extra fields found which i am not added on my table.Let me show my code with detail.

Migration table inquiry_plan detail:

```
public function up()
{
   Schema::create('inquiry_plan', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('inquiry_id');
        $table->string('title_vacation');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('phone_no', 20)->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('start_date')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('end_date')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('inquiry_id')->references('id')->on('inquiry_master');
    });
}
```

On my planController added a function for add activity:

Here is my controller function

```
 public function addactivity(Request $request) {
    try {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), Inquiryplan::planRules(), Inquiryplan::PlanMessages());
        $plandetails = Inquiryplan::SaveOrUpdate($request);
        if($plandetails !== false) {
            return redirect()->route('plan')->with('success', trans('Plan details added successfully.!!'));
        } else {
            return back()->with('error', "Unable to save plan details.!!")->withInput();
        }
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        dd($ex);
        return back()->with('error', "Unable to save plan details.!!")->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }
}
```

And finally saveOrupdate function in my model.

Here is my model function

```
public static function SaveOrUpdate(Request $request) {
    try {
        $id = $request->get('id', false);
        $plandetails = false;
        DB::transaction(function () use ($request, &$plandetails, $id) {
            $plandetails = $id ? Inquiryplan::findOrFail($id) : new Inquiryplan();
            $plandetails->fill($request->all());
            try {
                $plandetails->save();
            } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                throw $ex;
            }
            dd($ex);
        });
        return $plandetails;
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        throw $ex;
    }
}
```

When i submit my form it return error

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `inquiry_plan` (`inquiry_id`, `title_vacation`, `phone_no`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (0, test title, 9974031835, 2018-02-06, 2018-02-14, 2018-02-06 10:44:45, 2018-02-06 10:44:45))

what is the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add this fields to migration file and restart migration:

```
$table->timestamps();
```

all code:

```
public function up()
{
   Schema::create('inquiry_plan', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('inquiry_id');
        $table->string('title_vacation');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('phone_no', 20)->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('start_date')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('end_date')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('inquiry_id')->references('id')->on('inquiry_master');
    });
```

}

OR Simply place `public $timestamps = false;` in your model.

Answer (score 0):

In your model `Inquiryplan`, add this line:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

> By default, Eloquent expects `created_at` and `updated_at` columns to
>   exist on your tables.

So you need to add this on your migration file 
`$table->timestamps();` 
or if you don't want the timestamps at all add this to your Model File `public $timestamps = false;`